# Aussprache von „wol seyn“

Tags: pronunciation

Ist die Aussprache von *wol seyn* dieselbe wie bei *wohl sein*? (Stichwort: *Der Wanderer an den Mond* von Seidl).

Comment: Das hängt davon ab. Wenn es mittelhochdeutsch ist, dann ist die Aussprache anders. Das o in _Wol_ wird dann kurz gesprochen.

Comment: Das Gedicht "Der Wanderer an den Mond" ist neuhochdeutsch, nur wenige Worte sind in einer alterthümllichen Orthographie.

Comment: Ort und Zeit sollte der Fragesteller selbst recherchieren und mitteilen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Gedicht *Der Wanderer an den Mond* stammt von Johann Gabriel Seidl. Er lebte von 1804 bis 1875 in Wien. Der damals ebenfalls in Wien lebende Komponist Franz Schubert hat es im Jahr 1826 vertont, da war Seidl 22 Jahre alt. Man kann also davon ausgehen, dass das Gedicht entweder 1826 oder kurz davor erschienen ist.

Damit sind wir eindeutig in einer Zeit, in der Neuhochdeutsch gesprochen wurde. Natürlich gibt es aus der ersten Hälfte des 19. Jahrhunderts keine Tonaufzeichnungen, aber alles spricht dafür, dass die Aussprache damals im Wesentlichen so war wie zu der Zeit, als die ersten Tonfilme in Wien gedreht wurden ([Wiener Filme](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_Film)). Da in den Jahrzehnten nach diesen Filmen der Einfluss auf das in Wien gesprochene Deutsch sicher größer war als zwischen dem Erscheinen des Gedichts und diesen Filmen, und weil auch in den 1930-Jahren die Worte *»wohl«* und *»sein«* so wie heute ausgesprochen wurden, ist davon auszugehen, dass auch der Autor des Gedichts diese Worte damals so ausgesprochen hätte, wie man das heute tun würde.

Im Fall des Y in *»seyn«* spricht auch ein sprachwissenschaftliche Befund für die Aussprache als *sein*: Der Buchstabe Y wurde nämlich bis ins frühe 19. Jahrhundert hinein noch als [i] ausgesprochen (Quelle: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y#Verwendung_und_Aussprache_im_Deutschen)), und auch ich lernte als Schüler im Schuljahr 1971/72 den Buchstaben Y noch unter dem Namen *»Fremdes I«* kennen. Und ich selbst habe auch die Wörter *Ägypten, Forsythie, Glyzerin, Zylinder* und *Physik* neben der heute üblichen ü-Aussprache auch mit einem gesprochenen *I* kennengelernt. Der Fluss Ybbs (ein Zufluss zur Donau) und die gleichnamige Stadt werden auch heute noch wie *Ibs* ausgesprochen.

Für die lange Aussprache des O in *»wol«* spricht auch, dass neuhochdeutsch (bis auf einige wenige Ausnahmen) in der Schriftform lange Vokale nur dann besonders gekennzeichnet werden (z.B. o → oo, a → ah, i → ie), wenn in derselben Silbe auf den Vokal zwei (oder mehr) Konsonanten folgten. Zwei (oder mehr) Konsonanten am Ende einer Silbe (dazu zählen auch Doppel-Konsonanten) werden sonst nämlich als Hinweis auf einen kurzen Vokal interpretiert. Wenn also in einem neuhochdeutschen Wort auf einen Vokal nur ein einzelner Konsonant folgt, ist dieser Vokal in der Regel lang auszusprechen.

---

Anderes sähe es aus, wenn *wol seyn* aus einem mittelhochdeutschen Text stammen würde. Dann wäre das o kurz, aber *seyn* wurde auch in dieser wahrscheinlich wie *sain* ausgesprochen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just an old spelling for "wohl sein".

Comment: Warum antwortet ein deutscher Muttersprachler wie du in einer Fremdsprache, wenn jemand, der in Deutschland lebt, in deinem Deutsch-Forum auf Deutsch eine Frage über einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache stellt?

Comment: Ist das einfach nur deine persönliche Meinung, oder kannst du das auch so begründen, dass es für andere nachvollziehbar wird?

Comment: Vielleicht, weil er nicht-deutschsprachige Leser*innen erreichen will?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Die Leser, die aber die Frage auf Deutsch gut verstanden haben, und sich für die Antwort interessieren, die die Aussprache von einem deutschen Wort betrifft, obwohl sie kein Deutsch lesen können?

Comment: Der Grund ist bloße Unaufmerksamkeit (als ich die Antwort schrieb, war der Text der Frage schon aus dem Browserfenster gescrollt). Warum das nun so wichtig sein sollte, daß man darüber lang und breit diskutieren muß, ich mir allerdings auch nicht klar.

Comment: Die Begründung für "Ja, die Aussprache ist die dieselbe"
steht da: Es ist nur eine alte orthographische Variante.
Daß es sich um nicht mehr als eine (bis
ins 19. Jahrhundert übliche) orthographische Variante
in einem standardsprachlichen neuhochdeutschen Text
handelt, ist für jeden, der schon mal Texte in alter
Orthographie gelesen hat, ziemlich offensichtlich –
das bedarf keiner halbseitigen Erklärung.

Comment: @sermonionx Es kann ja bspw. sein, dass die Frage in einem Edit ins Englische übertragen wird.